# Cannot declare Public static final String s = new String("123") inside an inner class

Tags: java, constants, final, inner-classes

I tried to declare a class as shown below

```
class Outer{
    private final class Inner{
      public static final String s1 = new String("123");
      public static final byte[] bytes = new byte[]{0x00, 0x01};

      public static final String s2 = "123";
      public static final byte byte1 = 0x02;
    }
}
```

In the above code s1 and bytes wont compile but s2 and byte1 compile. If I put the whole constant declaration in outer class it works fine. what am i missing. Any help?

Comment: i bet the s2 line would have been *public static final String s2 = "123";*

Comment: @Cadrian, @Guido Sorry, Copy paste error, Updated the question

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Read Java Language Specification, 3rd ed, §8.1.3.

> An inner class is a nested class that is not explicitly or implicitly 
>   declared static. Inner classes may not declare static initializers (§8.7) or 
>   member interfaces.

This is why you cannot declare *new* `public static final String s1 = new String("123");`.

> Inner classes may not declare static members, unless they are compile-time 
>   constant fields (§15.28).

This explains why you can do `public static final String s2 = "123";`

A static nested class can have static members.

Comment: One should never say `new String("123")`, anyway: it's redundant, slow, and a waste of memory as you declare two variables and only use one. Just use the string literal: `"123"`.

Comment: Can you explain *why* JLS has this restriction?

Answer (score 0):

cf Java Language specification, second edition, [§8.1.2](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/classes.doc.html#262890)

> An inner class is a nested class that
>   is not explicitly or implicitly
>   declared static. Inner classes may not
>   declare static initializers (§8.7) or
>   member interfaces

Answer (score 0):

Inner classes were designed to work **in the context of the outer class**, I think static variables would break this rule.

> [8.1.2 Inner Classes and Enclosing Instances](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/classes.doc.html#262890)
>
> An inner class is a nested class that
>   is not explicitly or implicitly
>   declared static. Inner classes may not
>   declare static initializers (§8.7) or
>   member interfaces. Inner classes may
>   not declare static members, unless
>   they are compile-time constant fields
>   (§15.28).

Answer (score 0):

try this, it works fine inside an inner class:

```
public static final String  s="123";
```

I don't know the reason why it is allowed.