# Why does Java allow "public static final" in nested classes for simple types and not arrays?

Tags: java, jls

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cannot declare Public static final String s = new String(“123”) inside an inner class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4725505/cannot-declare-public-static-final-string-s-new-string123-inside-an-inner)

In the following example, why are CONST_ONE, CONST_TWO allowed, but CONST_THREE is flagged with the error "inner classes cannot have static declarations"?

```
package com.myco.mypack;

public final class Constants {

    public final class GroupOne {
        public static final String CONST_ONE = "stuff";
        public static final int CONST_TWO = 2;
        public static final int[] CONST_THREE = new int[]{3};
    }

    public static final int[] CONST_FOUR = new int[]{4};
}
```

I can get the behavior I need by using `public interface GroupOne` instead, but I'd still like to understand why the constants are treatly differently.  The only difference I see is that the third one is an array and therefore its members are modifiable, but it seems like that would trigger a different error if any.

Comment: It has been answered already. Basically only compile-time constant fields are allowed. Ref:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4725505/cannot-declare-public-static-final-string-s-new-string123-inside-an-inner

Comment: That does look like a duplicate question, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One point to note is your inner class (GroupOne) depends on the parent class (Constants) as you've defined it as `public final class GroupOne`. I suspect if you define it as `public static final class GroupOne` it will work for you.

The compiler error message should tell you this:

```
the field CONST_THREE cannot be declared static; static fields can only be declared in static or top level types
```

In your case, GroupOne is neither static, nor top level. It works for interfaces as they cannot be directly instantiated

Comment: Yeah, you're right.  I tried a number of variations, and could swear I had tried that one...but apparently NOT!